# Comparing cmd Output in Python

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I need to compare the output of a command in python to do if/else but. Unfortunately my Python skills are not that good yet.

The idea is to check with cmd if a Windows user exist or not and create or delete and then create him.

Can i use something like:

```
subprocess.check_output.Popen(command 'net user + USER +',stdout=PIPE)

if PIPE= ... 
command = ('net user '...)

else command = (...)
```

Comment: You're running the command "`net user + USER +`". That's not a valid command. You probably want something like "`'net user ' + user`".

Answer (score 0):

For if/else statement to work you need to end it by a colon (:) and provide indentation to the statement you need to execute.

```
if x == True:
    print ('x is True')
else:
    print ('x is False')
```

Comment: So u think my first part will work?
`subprocess.check_output.Popen(command 'net user + USER +',stdout=PIPE)`

Comment: subprocess.check_output('"net user" + USER',stdout=PIPE)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.check_output("net user",stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
print(p)
```

And it runs the command net user on the command line and prints the output. But I'm not sure if that's what you wanted. Can you clarify? Or If this helped, please check this as your answer, so that it helps others in the SO community. Thanks :)

EDIT:
This is not the most elegant way of checking if a user exists, but you get the idea.
With the if-else statments:

```
import subprocess

user = 'iamuser'
success = 'The command completed successfully'
p = subprocess.check_output('net user ' + user,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
if(success in str(p)):
    print('iamuser exists!')
else:
    print('nope, iamuser does not exist!')
```

Now you say you want to add or remove users, so I'm still trying to figure out how to do that because as far as I know, that requires the command line to be run as an administrator. But this is a start. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, i need to work with the output of the command. So if the User not exists the cmd says something like "User not exists" i'd like to run something like 
`if OUTPUT="User exsist" command (net user XXX /delete)
else (net user XXX /add)`

Comment: Yes, you will need to store the output in a string like I did, and then check the string for substrings in accordance with your condition.And instead of command, you will need to use the subprocess module like I did.

Also, why did I get downvoted?

Comment: Could you please paste an example for that with an if and else statement?